# Flutter SearchAnchor set cursor to another position

Tags: flutter

I use the widget "SearchAnchor" in flutter, but seems like this widget has some bugs. Currently, I struggle with the text selection. In the image below, you can see the cursor is currently at the end of the text. I try now to set the cursor by tapping on the input field to another position, but when the user taps directly on the input field, nothing happens. Does anybody have a solution how to fix that bug?

Btw also in the web-version exist this bug. I tried it directly in the flutter example [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchAnchor-class.html).

[image]

A code example of the widget below:

```
SearchAnchor(
            searchController: controller,
            builder: (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.openView();
                },
              );
            },
            suggestionsBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
              return List<ListTile>.generate(5, (int index) {
                final String item = 'item $index';
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(item),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.closeView(item);
                    });
                  },
                );
              });
            }),
```

Comment: can you add code snippet of this widget?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question now directly with an example from the widget. The full example can you directly see when you press on the link in the question, where you come to the flutter example page.